# Validate JSON response with array values

Tags: json, api

I have a JSON response as shown below (in array values). I want to validate whether the Keys (attributes) are properly retrieved in the Response. I would like to compare a list of expected values against the response values (only the first set of array values)
Eg:

```
"participants": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Kim",
        "LastName": "Hykes",
        "Street1": "ABC",
        "Street2": "ABCD",
        "City": "city1",
        "State": "NJ" 
    }

    {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "David",
        "Street1": "XYZ",
        "Street2": "UXYZ",
        "City": "city2",
        "State": "NY" 
     } 
]
```

Using JSONparser, the above JSON is parsed and the result will be:

```
participants[0].FirstName, participants[0].LastName, 
participants[0].Street1, participants[0].Street2, participants[0].City, 
participants[0].State, participants[1].FirstName, 
participants[1].LastName, 
participants[1].Street1, participants[1].Street2, participants[1].City, 
participants[1].State
```

And it goes on until 50 participants

I would like to see whether all the required Keys are fetched from the database and would like to check only the first Array fields i.e. only in Participants[0].

Can anyone help me to figure the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this, to validate whether the keys are in there, and in the correct order?

```js
var response = {"participants": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Kim",
        "LastName": "Hykes",
        "Street1": "ABC",
        "Street2": "ABCD",
        "City": "city1",
        "State": "NJ" 
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "David",
        "Street1": "XYZ",
        "Street2": "UXYZ",
        "City": "city2",
        "State": "NY" 
     } 
]
}
var keysNeeded = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Street1', 'Street2', 'City', 'State']

var i = 0;

for (key in response.participants[0]) {
 if (key == keysNeeded[i]) {
 console.log('all is OK with key '+key)
 }
 i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stacey, that answers only half of my query. But still im looking for a better solution. I want to loop through all my array elements and fetch only the first set of keys in a given 60 repeated array keys (for 10 different participants). need to fetch only first 6 keys. array need to be looped and as soon as it encounters the repeated key the loop should come out.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean here. I see 6 keys - FirstName, LastName, Street1, Street2, City, and State. When you say '60 repeated array keys' - do you mean these keys * 10?  Also, when you say 'only first 6 keys' - you don't mean the first occurrence of these 6 keys? Please try to write come code yourself as an example, and perhaps I can fix it for you.